# Error starting apache web server on raspberry pi

Tags: linux, apache-httpd

I am attempting setting up my raspberry pi to be a web server. I have just installed the program today, so it is on latest configuration. I have gone with apache2. I have read that if entering my computer's ip address into chrome does not pull up the sample page, I should use the linux command

```
sudo service apache2 start
```

However, when I try getting the code to run, I get the following message:

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I then open the first file it asks me to check, and this is what pulls up:

```
Jun 01 18:59:27 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jun 01 18:59:27 raspberrypi apachectl[6989]: /usr/sbin/apachectl: 174: /usr/sbin/apachectl: /usr/sbin/apachectl: /usr/sbin/apache2: not found
Jun 01 18:59:27 raspberrypi apachectl[6989]: Action 'start' failed.
Jun 01 18:59:27 raspberrypi apachectl[6989]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Jun 01 18:59:27 raspberrypi systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=127
Jun 01 18:59:27 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Jun 01 18:59:27 raspberrypi systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 01 18:59:27 raspberrypi systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

can anybody help?

Comment: This is saying that `/usr/sbin/apache2` is missing. How did you install `apache2` and which linux OS are you running?

Comment: whatever raspbian release was most recent.

Comment: I used     sudo apt-get install apache2

Comment: aparrently I forgot to install apache2-utils as well...

Comment: nope, did not fix the issue.

Comment: Try running `find / -name "apache2"` see if that binary is somewhere else

Comment: I am now trying to wipe it out of my system. I ran `whereis apache2` after `sudo apt-get purge apache2` and got this: `apache2: /usr/lib/apache2 /etc/apache2 /usr/share/apache2` any body know how to remove this?